# How to avoid having users enroll for multiple certificates?

Tags: windows, encryption, active-directory, certificate

I am the domain administrator of my company. Recently one of my clients has re-installed his Windows and received a new certificate from CA, but the key pair of certificate is not same with previous one, so he lost his encrypted emails.

Now, I want to know if there is any way to avoid issuing a new certificate by certificate issuer and reassign the old certificate to a user who changed his Windows? What about when he has other devices like PDAs or smartphones that need unique certificate installed on them in order to read encrypted emails on his Exchange mailbox with these devices?

Answer (score 1):

Multiple certificates can cause issues.

There is an option within the certificate template that can help.

It requires that certificates be published to AD.

Check the box "Do not automatically reenroll if a duplicate certificate exists in Active Directory"

Full details here on TechNet: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mspfe/archive/2012/12/27/how-to-avoid-having-users-enroll-for-multiple-certificates.aspx